# gcc/gfortran 11 cannot find headers/libraries in default locations

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake, homebrew, apple-m1

After upgrading python 3.8.6 to 3.9.10 using homebrew, my Cython extensions no longer without explicitly adding `/usr/local/include` (for my Intel MacBook) or `/opt/homebrew/include` to the `include_dirs` of my extension.

My setup.py.in:

```
import os, sys
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

link_arguments = []
extra_include_dirs = []
if (sys.platform == 'darwin'):
    link_arguments.append("-Wl,-rpath")
    link_arguments.append("-Wl,@loader_path/")
    if os.path.exists('/opt/homebrew/'):
        extra_include_dirs.append("/opt/homebrew/include/")
    else:
        extra_include_dirs.append("/usr/local/include/")
else:
    link_arguments.append("-Wl,-rpath=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/")

pynwp_extension = Extension(
    name="pynwp",
    sources=["${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lambert.f90", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pynwp.f90", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/readAtmosphereGen.f90", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ptogrot.f", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bilin1.f", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fl2pres_f.f","${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/message.c","${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gridWindDirCorrection.F"],
    libraries=["HirlamUtils_fPIC", "eccodes_f90", "jasper"],
    library_dirs=["${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}", "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/src/libHirlamUtils/", "/opt/homebrew/lib/"],
    extra_link_args = link_arguments,
    include_dirs=["${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include", "/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/",
                "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"] + extra_include_dirs,
    extra_f90_compile_args=["-DLINUX", "-DIS_LITTLE_ENDIAN", "-DUSEWALLTIME", "-DHAS_BLAS", "-DHAS_LAPACK", "-DGRIB32", "-DTIMING", "-DPREC32", "-fno-whole-file", "-g", "-fbounds-check"]
    #compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
)

setup(name="pynwp",
    author="me",
    author_email="me!me.com",
    version="1.0.1",
    description="Python wrapper for pynwp",
    package_dir={"": "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"},
    url="http://emaddc.eu",
    license="MIT License",
    ext_modules=[pynwp_extension]
    )
```

In the file above, I have hardcoded the location (temporarily) of the homebrew library dir and added some functionality for the include dir based on /opt/homebrew being found. If I remove this from the file, compilation fails as `eccodes.mod` cannot be found, see the output when I run the command generate by python/CMake manually:

```
buildDebug git:(master) ✗ /opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I<project_dir>//include -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/ -I<project_dir>//buildDebug -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9 -I/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/distutils/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c -c <project_dir>//src/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90 -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-3.9<project_dir>//src/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.o -DLINUX -DIS_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DUSEWALLTIME -DHAS_BLAS -DHAS_LAPACK -DGRIB32 -DTIMING -DPREC32 -fno-whole-file -g -fbounds-check
    f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory '/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules/' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
    f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory 'build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
    f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory 'build/src.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/numpy/distutils/include' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
    <project_dir>//src/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90:3:7:
    
        3 |   use eccodes
          |       1
    Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'eccodes.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

This extension is part of a larger project that is build using CMake. When running the gfortran command manually, the same errors indicating that `eccodes.mod` cannot be found. The file is however located on a default location on the gfortran/gcc search path:

```
locate eccodes.mod
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eccodes/2.24.2/include/eccodes.mod
/opt/homebrew/include/eccodes.mod
```

And the search path for gfortran:

```
gfortran -E -Wp,-v -
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/homebrew/include
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/bin/../lib/gcc/11/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/11/include
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/bin/../lib/gcc/11/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/11/include-fixed
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

Another project uses gcc/ld and has a similar problem. I need to explicitly add `LINK_DIRECTORIES(/opt/homebrew/lib)` to CMakeList.txt in order for gcc to find the eccodes library. Without that, I get:

```
gcc-11: warning: this compiler does not support X86 (arch flags ignored)
ld: library not found for -leccodes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/smoothModeS-v51/smoothModeS-v51.x] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/smoothModeS-v51/CMakeFiles/smoothModeS-v51.x.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Adding the paths to CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH had no effect.

This method works but seems hard to maintain. What am I missing and what has changed that gfortran/gcc no longer search in the default paths for but libraries and headers/modules?

**EDIT**

Just found that the standalone executable that uses similar code as the python extension and also uses `eccodes` has a similar issue. If I do not include `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/homebrew/include)` in CMakeLists.txt , I get:

```
cd <project_dir>/buildDebug/src/collocEHS && /opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran  -I<project_dir>/buildDebug -I<project_dir>/include -I<project_dir>/src/readASTERIX2 -I<project_dir>/src/geomag70_linux -I<project_dir>/src/libDTG -fallow-argument-mismatch -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -DPREC32 -DLINUX -DIS_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DUSEWALLTIME -DHAS_BLAS -DHAS_LAPACK -DGRIB32 -DTIMING -ffixed-line-length-none  -g -fcheck=all -Wall -fcheck=bounds -O0 -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -c <project_dir>/src/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90 -o CMakeFiles/collocEHSv2.dir/__/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90.o
<project_dir>/src/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90:3:7:

    3 |   use eccodes
      |       1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'eccodes.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/collocEHS/CMakeFiles/collocEHSv2.dir/__/pynwp/readAtmosphereGen.f90.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/collocEHS/CMakeFiles/collocEHSv2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I guess the problem is unrelated to python but more with gcc/gfortran (gcc version 11.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3).

**EDIT 2**

A reboot of the laptop fixed the issue with the python extension build and setup.py requiring additional directories. For normal builds using CMake, I still require the extra `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `LINK_DIRECTORIES` order for gcc/gfortran to find libraries installed by brew in /opt/homebrew (or /usr/local for intel MacBook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per homebrew devs, this is desired behaviour: `/opt/homebrew` and `/usr/local` are "special" directories to be manually added in e.g., CMake projects. This is explained in my bug report on home-brew's GitHub, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/95561.

I haven't been able to confirm this with documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).